# ios- issue of over sizing with aviary's own view controller in ios 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios6.1, aviary

Tested the app in both ios 6.1 and 7.1.

Issue of view controller arised when tested in ios 6.1, both on simulator and the physical device.

The horizontal scroll menu in ios 6.1 is not completely viewable.

Attached the screen-shots of the running Aviary view controller in both ios versions.

Please suggest a way to over come this issue.

ios 6.1 screenshot below

[image]

ios 7.1 retina screen shot below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the iOS 6 SDK, please make sure to call the following method on **AFPhotoEditorCustomization**:

`[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setUsingIOS6SDK:YES];`

If the issue persists, please also try upgrading to the latest version of the SDK.

Comment: Yes buddy, as per the reply from the forum, I updated SDK and solved the problem.